# How to prevent wrapping/breaking a sentence : react native

Tags: css, react-native

I have to prevent a two word sentence('**View More**', see image) from wrapping as its a link whose words needs to be together. React native does not support **white-space** property in css, so a solution is required! See image below:

[image: reference image]

Also see the code structure:

```
<View style={styles.rewardsAction}>
  <Text style={styles.rewardsInfo}>AED 20 of 100 can be redeemed.  
     <Text style={styles.viewmore} numberOfLines={1}>View More</Text>
  </Text>
  <Text style={styles.rewardsApply}>Apply</Text>
</View>
```

And its corresponding css:

```
rewardsAction:{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-between', flexWrap: 'wrap', borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#eaeaea', paddingHorizontal: 10, paddingVertical: 10, borderRadius: 10  },
rewardsInfo:{width: '80%'},
rewardsApply:{ color: 'red'},
viewmore: {width: 80, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#000', textDecorationLine: 'underline', color: 'skyblue', flexWrap: 'nowrap'},
```

I had also searched internet for solution but they are not related to this! Any situational quick fix would also be helpful!

**EDIT**:
I have got some answers below and I think there is some confusion, **View More** text should be together either in that single line or should go below, '**Apply**' text is separated to right, and '**View More**' should be with that sentence!

Comment: A `&nbsp;` as _space_ often solves that.

Comment: Btw, you are able to target the rendered html with an external CSS, where `white-space` can be set.

Answer (score 2):

Use `&nbsp;` in static texts rigt in JSX.

Use `text.replace(/\s/g, '\xa0')` for replacing whitespace by non-breaking space in variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<View style={styles.rewardsAction}>
  <View style={{flexDirection:'row',flexWrap:'wrap'}}>
   <View>
      <Text style={styles.rewardsInfo}>AED 20 of 100 can be redeemed.</Text>
   </View>
   <View>   
     <Text style={styles.viewmore} numberOfLines={1}>View More</Text>
   </View>
  </View>
  <Text style={styles.rewardsApply}>Apply</Text>
</View>
```

You could have something like above. If space is there, the 'View More' will come in same line, else it will move to the next line.

Comment: "View More text should be together either in that single line or should go below, 'Apply' text is separated to right, and 'View More' should be with that sentence" - It is doing the same, The 'View More' Text will be in same line if space permits it, else it will move to next line. and apply will stay where it is, as it is direct children of View having rewardAction.

Answer (score 0):

You are using clubbed Text, so that JustifyContent wont work. Instead try to bind with View tags like this.

```
<View style={{flex: 'row', JustifyContent: 'space-between'}>
     <View>  
         <Text>AED 20 of 100 can be redeemed.</Text> 
     </View>

     <View>
          <Text>View More</Text>
     </View>

     <View>
          <Text style={{color:'red'}}>Apply</Text>
     </View>

</View>
```

Try to not apply, other styles like width etc in Text tag, instead use those in View tag.

Comment: ya, i understood the question. By my above answer it will bring as you expected !. Else if you want View More to come below the text, Combine first two View tag under  a View Tag with Flex Direction as "column"